# Android Fragment - Detect if view is active/visible

Tags: android, android-fragments

Refresh code

```
   public void viewRefresh(){
        getProgressBar(R.id.spinnerBar).setAlpha(1);  // CRASH HERE. FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

On Resume Code

```
  public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        viewRefresh();


   API.getInstance().bidOnAuction(auctionID, bid, new JsonHttpResponseHandler(){

                    @Override  // this code is calls refresh after 3 or so seconds.
                    public void onSuccess(JSONObject results) {
                        // BID Successfully
                        Log.i("BID ", "SUCCESS");
                        viewRefresh();
```

I have an android app API 19. I have some async code that cools a redraw.
What I have found that if I load the fragment, then before the callback has occurred, I pop the fragment. The view is gone but the code keeps executing. And therefore. I cannot get access to my Progressbar.

How do detect if my fragment view is still active? (without complex fragment tagging logic?)

Comment: The `Fragment` class has methods for that checking, doesn't it? Like `isAdded()`, `isDetached()`...

Comment: Finally! Thanks, I have been looking for this for ages. But everyone was pointing at different methods. Please add that as answer and I will mark it as accepted!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Fragment class has methods for that checking, such as `isAdded()`, `isDetached()`, etc.

`Fragment.isAdded()` probably will work for you.